# Set the parameters of the certificate in the openssl req command line

Tags: ssl, command, certificate, optional-parameters

When I want to generate a new certificate (I've previously generated key), I write the following command in the console, example:

```
openssl req -new -key my-prvkey.pem -x509 -days 365 -out mypubcert.pem
```

Then, the system asks me to provide a set of parameters to generate the certificate, such as:

Country Name, State or province Name, Locality Name, Organization Name, Organizational Unit Name, Common Name and Email Address

Once I provide the above parameters the certificate is generated without problems, however, is it possible to generate the certificate so that in the same command parameters are sent?

So the system did not ask the parameters one by one, but I will be sent from the first call to the command?

I hope I explained, now I appreciate any help.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html) it is possible to specify a subject

```
openssl req -new -key my-prvkey.pem -subj 'CN=my new cert/C=SK' -x509 -days 365 -out mypubcert.pem
```